# Can't see class inside DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently refactoring a lot of code from an Asp.Net web application, so it can easily be replicated in other projects.

In this instance, I've created a new CMS project (DLL), which includes an Entity Framework ORM over a CMS database - the idea being that you can just add a reference, set the connection string and go.

However, there's still a bit more to do.

The Web App has a base page. The base page is the only Class to access the CMS project, so I though why not move the base page functionality inside the DLL - after all it's just a class, rather than recreate the same functionality for each new web app.

So, I've done just that.

I copied the base page class to the external project, updated the namespace and recompiled the project.

However, when I try to inherit the base page like this:

Page in web app:

```
public partial class HowItWorks : MyCo.MyProject.CmsBasePage
```

In external project:

```
namespace MyCo.MyProject
{
    public class CmsBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
}
```

I can't see the class in intellisense (Visual Studio).

I've rechecked the namespace and recompiled but no joy.

First time I've worked this way so it could be an error on my part or it could be that I need to do something else to make the class accessible. I'm not sure.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Clean and re-build. Check the reference. Check that you're targeting the same framework version.

Comment: So far looks fine

Comment: Yes, there's some issue somewhere. The project recompiles but I'm not seeing any updates in the web app - at least I know I'm not missing something now - just need to chase the issue.

Comment: Do you actually have a reference to the project you copied your class to?

Comment: @nvoigt - yes, I'm current using the DLL functionality, but I can't access any new functionality I've added. I've even removed the reference, deleted the DDL and re-established.

Comment: Very odd - I have a solution but not an answer. I forced an update by making a change inside another namespace - and things miraculously updated. good old VS - can't wait to get the next unstable update. Thanks for your help guys.